# How to convert Div data into json format using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

This is my html code. I want this div id "con" will be call when export button click then it show json data in console.

if anyone know please help

```
<html>
  <div id ="con">
    <div>Name : P</div>
    <div>Age : 20</div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="append()">Export</button>
</html>
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Adding an event to your button?  Outputting to the console?  Reading the id?  Generating a javascript object? Converting a js object to json?  Outputting to the console?  What's your expected output?  "json" is just a notation, you need to specify what format that takes. Please be specific.   If you include what you've tried, it might be easier to narrow down your issue.

Comment: how to write jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method, I've added `class` attribute to your button:

```js
$('.conSubmit').on('click', function() {
  var JSONObj = {};
  var divArr = $('#con div');

  $.each(divArr, function(index, val) {
    var data = val.innerText;
    var dataArray = data.split(':');
    index == 0 ? JSONObj.name = dataArray[1].trim() :
      JSONObj.Age = dataArray[1].trim();
  })
  console.log(JSONObj);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con">
  <div>Name : P</div>
  <div>Age : 20</div>
</div>
<button class="conSubmit" type="submit">Export</button>
```